# Trouble adding a new service

Tags: service, cloud-foundry

I have followed the instructions at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/oss-docs/tree/master/vcap/adding_a_system_service and copied the echo service and created my new service. (That document is somewhat out-of-date in that "excluded components" no longer exists.

In any case, my service shows up as running with a gateway and a node when I look at 'vcap status' on the server. However, when I look at 'vmc services' from the client my service is not in the list. Where is this list maintained and why is my service not on the list?

Various services, including blob, filesystem, mongodb, etc, are shown on the 'vcm services' list even though they have never been included in my config. Where is this maintained and why are other services on this list?

The cloud_controller.log file shows a "Create service request:" for echo every minute. This service is not in my config file (it was once but it was removed and I repeated the deployment). What is prompting this request for a service that was not defined in the config?

The _gateway.log for my service shows the following:

- INFO -- Sending info to cloud controller: ...api.vcap.me/services/v1/offerings
- INFO -- Fetching handles from cloud controller .../offerings/.../handles
- ERROR -- Failed registering with cloud controller, status=400
- DEBUG -- [GaaS-Provisioner] Connected to node mbus..
- ERROR -- Failed fetching handles, status=404

Why does my gateway fail to register with the cloud controller? I have found some reports that suggest that the problem is with domain name mapping. I have verified that the server can find itself:

- `$curl api.vcap.me`
- `Welcome to VMware's Cloud Application Platform`

What can I do to register my service?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try asking your question on the vcap_dev google group.

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev

They are focused in answering and discussing OSS subjects for Cloud Foundry!

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the document correctly things should work just fine. I understand that the mechanism for maintaining the excluded list of components has changed and can be a point of confusion when following the steps mentioned in the article (just ignore that step totally).

> **ERROR -- Failed registering with cloud controller, status=400**

Well this is a point of worry. I recently followed the article step by step and was able to add a new service.

- Is the echo service showing up in vmc services?
- Have you copied the the yml files for node and gateway at  **./cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config**?
- Are the tokens for your gateway unique? and matching in the two files? **./cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config/cloud_controller.yml** and  **./cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config/****_gateway.yml**

I would recommend that you first concentrate on getting the echo service to be listed in the vmc services output. Once done with this you should replicate the steps (with absolute care to modify things like the token) to get your custom service working.

Cheers,

Ankit

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this [guide](http://corneliadavis.com/blog/2013/01/04/learning-how-to-add-services-to-cloud-foundry/)

It work to me.

regards.